# Div changing size when adding an img to it

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, size

I am making buttons on a page that look like app icons, i have put divs in a table to organise them, inside the div i want to put an image like a little icon and then text underneath but when i add the image the div changes size and messes with the table that its in.

The table is in a div that is called container that is set to 100% width and height of the screen

[This is what i want it to look like but with an image above the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6tZT.png)

[This is what happens when i add the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcLAC.png)

```css
    /* The table for the navigation buttons */
    table#buttonTable {
      position: relative;
      margin: 7.5% auto 0 auto;
      width: 90%;
      height: 68%;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #444;
      border-radius: 25px;
    }
    /* The navigation buttons */
    div.navigationButtons {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #282828;
      width: 55%;
      height: 55%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border-radius: 25px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1C1C1C inset;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1C1C1C inset;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1C1C1C inset;
      -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1C1C1C inset;
    }
    img#calcImg {
      position: relative;
      width: 20%;
      height: auto;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    /* Text in the navigation buttons */
    p.navButtonsText {
      position: relative;
      color: #008080;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      top: 75%;
      font-size: 200%;

    }
```

```html
<table id="buttonTable">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <div onclick="window.location = 'calculators.html';" id="calculatorsButton" class="navigationButtons">
        <img src="images/tealCalculator.png" id="calcImg" />
        <p class="navButtonsText">Calculators</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <div onclick="window.location = 'setupTips.html';" id="setupTipsButton" class="navigationButtons">
        <p class="navButtonsText">Setup Tips</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `p.navButtonsText { position: absolute; }` instead?

Comment: Changing the position to absolute doesn't make any difference, also if the text is too long it makes the div big like in the deformed picure

Answer (score 0):

```css
    /* The table for the navigation buttons */
    table#buttonTable {
      position: relative;
      margin: 7.5% auto 0 auto;
      width: 90%;
      height: 68%;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #444;
      border-radius: 25px;
    }
    /* The navigation buttons */
    div.navigationButtons {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #282828;
      width: 45%;
      height: auto;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border-radius: 25px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1C1C1C inset;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1C1C1C inset;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1C1C1C inset;
      -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1C1C1C inset;
    }
    img#calcImg {
      position: relative;
      width: 65%;
      height: auto;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    /* Text in the navigation buttons */
    p.navButtonsText {
      position: relative;
      color: #008080;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 120%;

    }
    
    table tr td {
      width: 200px;
      height: 230px;
    }
```

```html
<table id="buttonTable">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <div onclick="window.location = 'calculators.html';" id="calculatorsButton" class="navigationButtons">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/igh0zt/ios7-style-metro-ui/256/MetroUI-Apps-Mac-App-Store-icon.png" id="calcImg" />
        <p class="navButtonsText">Calculators</p>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <div onclick="window.location = 'setupTips.html';" id="setupTipsButton" class="navigationButtons">
        <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/igh0zt/ios7-style-metro-ui/256/MetroUI-Apps-Mac-App-Store-icon.png" id="calcImg" />
        <p class="navButtonsText">Setup Tips</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: is all you changed the bottom bit of css? if so can i use percentages for the width and height?

Comment: @AaronVance I also modified the font-size and adjusted the width for the example. Change the height, width and font-size once you added the image so you can test with that.

Comment: Thank you so much, it has worked a dream! I spent a whole night looking at this and not getting it to work!

Comment: @AaronVance I am glad it helped :)